# Angular 2 | 8 nested class - best option

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question about "nested classes", because I would like to build optimalized app.

For example I have two models / classes

```
export class A{
    public id: number;
}

export class B{
    public id: number;
    public a: A[];
}
```

and objects like that:

```
new B(1, [new A(1), new A(2), new A(3)]
new B(1, [new A(2), new A(3)]
new B(1, [new A(1), new A(3)]
```

As u can see there are many data which are duplicated (objs A). 
Of course it is only an example because in the A class are more fields (in the real world).

Now is the main question.
What is optimal (or maybe it doesn't matter) to keep every A obj in the B obj or maybe to keep in the B object only ids of A objects. Does angular reduce these data automatycally or not?

In the real app I would like to create form where user can chose color and structure of color. There are many duplicates of structures so I thinked that the ids of structures will be enought but im not sure. 
So what is better more duplicated data or more operation to do.

ADD:
I use Symfony4 as backend and there I have relationship in the DB (doctrime2) like OneToOne, ManyToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany. That is why I would like to find best approach.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is to use OOP and have class B extend class A so it can inherit those fields from A. You can then add more fields to class B as needed.

Comment: I don't think this question has to do with Angular at all.

Comment: Without seeing how the classes are instantiated it's difficult to advise. If the classes represent data that is returned by your backend, you need to go back to the drawing board. Also, as previously noted, this has nothing to do with angular. For that matter, it has nothing to do with typescript. It's a JavaScript question

Comment: Ok thanks for your advices. I will try to analyse it (compare) when I will be able. Now I have another problem with An8 because I'm begginer in this field.